# perl login and submit with WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, form-submit, www-mechanize

I have a standard form which logs my users into a separate site.

```
<form action="http://www.url.com/" name="loginform" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="pg" value="/index.cfm">
<input type="hidden" name="login" id="login" value="loginname"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="pwd" id="pwd" value="mypass">
<input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Using WWW::Mechanize I am able to insert username, password and submit,logging in with no problems.  The slight twist is that I don't want to print the page, but actually go to the website in question.  So ideally I would provide a link to the login script, autofill out the form and submit, and the user will be logged in to the site.

Of course I can pre-fill the form and the user simply needs to click submit, but I want to remove that step.

The site does not accept 'get' actions so it has to be 'post'.

To clarify, I have used the following code to log in, but instead of printing the page within the script, I want to end up on the landing page (after successful log in) on the other site!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);
use CGI ':standard';
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

my $url = "http://www.url.com/";

$mech->get($url);


my $result = $mech->submit_form(
form_name => 'loginform', #name of the form
#instead of form name you can specify
#form_number => 1
fields      =>
{
 login    => 'loginname', # name of the input field and value
 pwd    => 'mypass',
}
,button    => 'loginconsole_button' #name of the submit button
);

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
 print $result->content();
```

Comment: What page are you reaching as a result of this call? I don't see why the site would get you to the print page, unless the `$url` is referencing a `print` page

Comment: I'm using the word print in terms of outputting to window, not printing the page.  So WWW::Mechanize is logging me in properly, but the final 2 lines print etc reproduce  the page being read, but I want to redirect to the actual site, logged in.

Comment: I think you are expecting something that isn't there, WWW::Mechanize, runs code, and does what you tell you, it doesn't do anything else. You told it to output the data `print $result->content();`. You want it to redirect you? why would it redirect you? if the site redirects, that it redirects. That redirects will be inside `content()`, but WWW::Mechanize doesn't have to follow that redirect.

Comment: I can quite imagine that WWW::Mechanize isn't the way to do this.  It is successfully logging in, and is quite willing to report back to me on what it is seeing.  But I don't want that.  If I show the user the form at the start of the question, pre filled, and they click on the button, they will be logged in and taken to the correct page.  I would like to automate that precise process so they don't have to see the form or click submit.

Comment: The issue with what you propose is the user's session with your script and the session of the WWW::Mechanize are not the same one. Is login and password a secret to the user? or does he know them?

Comment: They know the login details. This is purely for convenience, so they can click the link in the menu, auto log in and carry on working in the new site.  I can do this by replacing the link in the menu with a button and that will achieve what I need.  but it is slightly less good in terms of presentation than having a link in the menu which activates the login and redirects.  Of course if it's not possible to do that then I'll have to stick to what's possible!  :)

Comment: Solve it using HTML and JS, I think perl code is not helpful. Also if it is your web application, then your problem is even easier solved than this, is it?

Comment: WWW::Mechanize follows 301/302 redirects just fine. It even has a callback mechanism you can use to selectively block them. META-EQUIV and JavaScript redirects won't work, obviously.